# Verify RSA-SHA256 xml in PHP (Signing in .NET and Verifying in PHP)

Tags: openssl, cryptography, rsa, php-openssl, rsa-sha256

I Receive XML request, contains MsgBody Tag, and Signature (the signing process done in **.net**),

I have to Verify the msg body they sent, with the signature, and the requester public key, but i cant.

my code is :

```
$msg_body = "<MsgBody><Transactions>....</Transactions></MsgBody>";
$signature = "nkI/Z/ySJSxarh..............==";
$verifying_flag = openssl_verify($msg_body, base64_decode($signature), PUBLIC_KEY, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
```

and i've tried this :

```
$rsa = new \Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(PUBLIC_KEY);
$verifying_flag = $rsa->verify($msg_body, base64_decode($signature));
```

the $verifying_flag failure in both ways,

the signing process done in .NET by this code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static string SignMessage(XElement xmlMessage, Collection<string> xPaths, string certificateSerialNumber)
    {
        string elementsValue = string.Empty;
        foreach (vara xPath in xpaths)
        {
            IEnumerable<XElement> xPathSelectElements = xmlMessage.XPathSelectElements(xPath);
            foreach (XElement xPathSelectElements in xPathSelectElements)
            {
                elementsValue += xPathSelectElements.ToString();
            }
        }

        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCryptoServiceProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsaCryptoServiceProvider.FromXmlString(GetCertificates(certificateSerialNumber).PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true));
        RSACryptoServiceProvider.UseMachineKeyStore = true;
        rsaCryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(false);
        rsaCryptoServiceProvider.KeySize = 2048;
        return Convert.ToBase64String(rsaCryptoServiceProvider.SignData(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(elementsValue), CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256")));
    }
```

how to verify their request ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are signing it using `SHA-256`, so you have to set it in PHP side:

```php
$rsa->setHash('sha256');
```

Secondly, you have to set signature mode to use the PKCS#1 scheme by default:

```php
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
```

And Finally, since you're using `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` on C#, you need to convert the message body on php to `UTF-16LE` before verifying it:

```php
$msg_body = mb_convert_encoding($msg_body, 'UTF-16LE');
```

At the end, the code should be like this:

```php
$rsa = new \Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(PUBLIC_KEY);

$rsa->setHash('sha256');
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$msg_body = mb_convert_encoding($msg_body, 'UTF-16LE');

$verifying_flag = $rsa->verify($msg_body, base64_decode($signature));
```

## UPDATE

If you want to generate the message signature on PHP, you can easily do this:

```php
$rsa = new \Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(PRIVATE_KEY);

$rsa->setHash('sha256');
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$msg_body = mb_convert_encoding($msg_body, 'UTF-16LE');

$signature = base64_encode($rsa->sign($msg_body));
```

BTW, you can avoid converting the message encoding by removing the `mb_convert_encoding` line on both ways (verify & sign)